# use grep to match pattern R

Tags: r

I have a series of characters such as

```
"TB=7"
"RT=9"
"UI=19"
"RT=91"
```

all of them are saved in a varibale called tu. When I write

```
grep("RT=9",tu, values=TRUE)
```

I do get RT=9 and RT=91 as outputs. But I only want RT=9. Is there a way to do that?

Thnaks

Answer (score 3):

If you want an exact match, why use regular expressions? Just

```
tu == "RT=9"
```

will work perfectly (but it returns a boolean vector rather than the indices or the values). In order to get back the values, use `tu[tu == "RT=9"]`. To get indices, use `which`. Alternatively, assuming that you are searching for a unique exact match in a table of unique elements, `match` might also be appropriate:

```
hit <- match('RT=9', tu) # hit == 2
```

That said, you can also perform full-stream matching with `grep` by specifying that the string should contain *nothing else*:

```
grep("^RT=9$",tu, values=TRUE)
```

`^` and `$` match the start and the end of the string, respectively. Have a look at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which is a great reference.

Comment: +1 and I hope (again) that the OP will consider accepting an answer this time.

Comment: Let's add that `tu[tu == "RT=9"]` doesn't carry a lot of info other than how many matches where found. So the OP will most likely prefer to use just `tu == "RT=9"` like you first suggested. He can then wrap it inside `sum` to get the number of matches, or `which` to get the indices.

Comment: And since the OP's example contains unique ids, let's also mention `match`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
grep('^RT\=9$', tu, values=TRUE)
```

Comment: if i try this \= is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "^RT"... ideas?

Comment: Maybe try without the \  I think the = sign doesnt need to be escaped. =)